# relation "background_task" does not exist

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run some tasks in the background while running a django server. To do this, I'm using background-tasks library. I've followed the following steps:

1. `pip install django-background-tasks`
2. Added `'background_task'`, in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
3. `python manage.py makemigrations background_task`

The problem arises in the 3rd step giving an error stating:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "background_task" does not
>   exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "background_task" ("task_name",
>   "task_params", "...

I've tried looking for other solutions but every one of them was the 3rd line.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: did you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: yes. giving the same error

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still valid question but what helped me was to revert all changes in code related to `background_task` module and then applying migrations. After that reapply your changes in code and it should all work.

Answer (score 0):

After the 2nd step go to command line and do following :
1. python manage.py showmigrations (check if it works fine)
2. python manage.py migrate (check if the background task file is added to the show migrations list eg:
background_task
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20170927_1109)
3. Now make modifications in your views in which ever way you want to use the backgroundtasks.